# Units of Larmor frequency

Tags: electromagnetism, units, si-units, unit-conversion

I'm sorry if this is really basic, but what exactly is the unit of Larmor frequency? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession), the formula for Larmor frequency is:
$$\omega = \frac{egB}{2m}$$

and with $g$ as a dimensionless constant, we work out the units of $\omega$ to be:
\begin{equation}
[\omega] = \frac{(A\cdot{s})({kg\cdot s^{-2}\cdot A^{-1}})}{kg} =s^{-1}
\end{equation} 
which is all good.

But when we include Thomas Precession, Wikipedia (it's on the same page) offers the formula to be:
$$\omega_{s(g=2)} = \frac{eB}{mc\gamma}$$
which, upon comparison with the original formula above, is obviously different. More precisely, the units of Larmor frequency is now $m^{-1}$. What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for Thomas Precession is in [CGS units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Various_extensions_of_the_CGS_system_to_electromagnetism), whereas the formula you provided for Larmor Precession is in SI.